# Focusing using javascript doesn't show outline style for checkbox like it does when use Tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

When navigating through inputs on the page using tab, they become outlined once in focus. But when I try to do something similar using, for example, arrow keys, focusing on checkboxes doesn't show outline styles.

```
jq(elems).keydown(function(e){
    if(!e) return;
    if(e.keyCode == '38') {
        var el = ... // searching for the next element
        el.focus();
    }
```

Even if I manually add outline styles after focus, or add css like

```
input[type="checkbox"]:focus 
{
  outline-style:auto; 
  outline-color: 
 -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}
```

it wouldn't work. The focus is on the checkbox, the styles are there, but they are not displayed. Some other styles applied correctly, for example if I add styles like:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
    box-shadow:1px 1px lightgrey;
}
```

I can see shadow box when focus is on the checkbox, but outline is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only done this in raw js, but hopefully it helps:

Make sure to set the event listener on the document - otherwise you're only firing the event if the key is pressed whilst already 'inside' the element.

JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById('my-check');
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  el.focus();
});
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:focus, input[type="checkbox"]:active {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline-color: -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-style: solid !important;
}
```

DOM:

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="my-check" />
</form>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/radmpxgs/1/

*Sorry for the edits.*

Comment: Thanks for response. But the thing is that if I add style like this
input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
    box-shadow:1px 1px lightgrey;
}
it works correctly, I see the shadow box when focus is on the checkbox. But outline style doesn't work...

Comment: @OleksiiBezuhlyi

Ah - add 'outline-style: solid !important;'

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/radmpxgs/1/

(Updated original answer)

Comment: Making it important doesn't help. I can see the outline style in element inspector, but it's not actually rendered on the element.

Comment: @OleksiiBezuhlyi Can you see it working in the jsfiddle?